.NET 7 wasm does not see file in Linux
I was trying to set up running .NET from node.js using the Microsoft guide via dotnet workload install wasm-experimental and dotnet new wasmconsole.
I want to read the vsdx file from .NET, but I have the error:

Error reading file: Could not find a part of the path
'/home/user/project/src/file.vsdx'

The .Net application:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Linq;

return 0;
public partial class MyClass
{
  [JSExport]
  internal static string Greeting()
  {
    try {
      string filePath = "/empty-template.vsdx";

      if (File.Exists(filePath))
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Файл существует по пути: " + filePath);
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Файл не существует по пути: " + filePath);
      }

      try {
        File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error reading file: {ex.Message}");
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      Console.WriteLine($"Error opening package: {ex.Message}");
    }

    return "filePath";
  }

The file exists by path.

filePath should use relative paths, not absolute paths. You should change it like below:
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    _env = env;
}

var contentRootPath = _env.ContentRootPath;
string filePath = Path.Combine(contentRootPath, "src", "empty-template.vsdx");

Suggestion
Please set a breakpoint and check the filePath is correct or not. The code above is a sample, you should change it according to your needs.
